# Angular JS orderBy does not work with ngInfiniteScroll

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I am looping over an array of objects in Angular JS. I have multiple filters applied and I am also using ngInfiniteScrolling for lazy load. Everything works fine except I can't use any sorting. Whatever `orderBy` I apply nothing changes at all. Here's my code:

```
<div infinite-scroll='loadMoreFilter()' infinite-scroll-distance='0' ng-show="showFilter">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="product in (productsFiltered = (products | filter: { Prdha : filterBrand } | filter : { Matkl : filterCategory.categoryCode } | filter : { Pltyp : filterCatalogue } | filter : { inWishlist : filterFavorites } | filter : hideNA() )) | limitTo:totalDisplayed" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
    <!-- some code -->
    </div>
</div>
```

If I add `| orderBy : myField` after the last filter (before the limitTo) nothing changes, it's like the sorting is not applied. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have a bunch of filter expressions instead of one? Is `myField` a variable in the current scope that holds a string or a function?

Comment: Yeah I know that I can use a single function but the problem appears even if I use a single filter. With myField I tried pretty much everything, even a string.